# How to create customized map views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

Is it possible to customize the look of maps in iPhone. I am unable to do it using the `MapKit.framework`. Does anyone know how to do it with the existing framework or in any other way?

Comment: Is there any kind of api which can change the look of the map view because by using it I am not able to change the look of map view

Comment: How do you want to customize the map? Do you want to add custom pins? Bitmap overlay? Your question isn't quite clear.

Comment: I want to change the color of map view I want to change from blue to black

Comment: you mean the background color of the google map where the tiles haven't been loaded yet?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of Research I finally found the link of Google api which allow to create your

custom map view.Basically they provide a link which you need to open in web view and it will

return you an image listed the link below :

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/05/20/make-your-google-map-stand-out-with-styles/

Thanks

Rohit Sharma

Answer (score 0):

first add the framework

Then make sure to #import

the map is declared like this in a header file:

```
MKMapView *mapView;
```

to show the location of the user:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [MapKit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html), to add `MKMapView` to your app.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. You can use the MKOverlayView class to draw your own map in a MKMapView.